# Retrieving and displaying dynamic content from SQL database into ASP.NET pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently working on the development of news portal website in asp.net. I have created a table in sql server 2008 with parameters (NewsId, NewsTitle, NewsDetails, NewsCategory). I am now able to dynamically retrieve the NewsTitle from the database and displaying it in my aspx page. 
Now I want to pass the NewsId for that particular NewsTitle and then retrieve the NewsDetails in a separate aspx page. What is the best thing to do this in ASP.NET? I don't want to create new aspx pages every time a link to the NewsTitle is clicked, rather I am interested to use the same Details page and pass different ID parameters?

regards,

Comment: well then pass the parameter via session or query string ! !

Comment: learn to use database classes defined in C# (if you use ASP.NET with C#) or VB.NET. Get a book and read it. There will provide many examples using databases.

Answer (score 2):

I'd keep them both on the same page and employ a master-details pattern using something like panels to toggle the visibility:

http://leedumond.com/blog/master-detail-editing-inserting-deleting-with-a-listview-and-detailsview/

This will give you the basic idea; the sample linked to shows both, but as I said it is a simple matter to toggle them on and off on the click of a button.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following approach:

1. Take HyperLink in a Gridview to show a NewsTitle:

   ```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
       <Columns>
           <asp:TemplateField>
               <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hl" NavigateUrl='<%#"NewsDetails.aspx?Newsid="+ Eval("NewsId") %>' Text='<%# Eval("NewsTitle") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
       </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
   ```

   Bind the GridView datasource in code behind:

   ```
   protected void getNewsDetails()
   {
       DataTable dtNewsDetails = new DataTable();
       //retrieve data from database into the DataTable
       GridView1.DataSource = dtNewsDetails;
       GridView1.DataBind();
   }
   ```
2. Now as GridView HyperLink will navigate to the NewsDetails.aspx with a NewsId as querystring, show the details accordingly in a NewsDetails.aspx page:

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          string Newsid = Request.QueryString["Newsid"].ToString();
          //show the details from database using Newsid
      }

Comment: Thank you Ashwin. This seems interesting and I will let you know once i tried it.

Comment: It is working fine now. I followed your guidelines except that I used FormView instead of GridView to display the NewsTitle and NewsDetails.    Thank you once again

Comment: I just given an idea! please mark as an answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a textBox with visible attribute set as False and when you retrieve the NewsDetails set it to textBox and set it visibility to True;

```
<asp:TextBox ID="NewsDetails" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                        Height="30px" Width="200px" Visible="False" />
```

and

```
void GetNewsDetails()
{
NewsDetails.Text=GetDetailsQuery;
NewsDetails.Visible=True;
}
```

Comment: Why would you display news in a `TextBox` ?

Comment: You can use any control like label that is just an example for displaying on the same page.