# button in gridview to connect another page

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a asp.net 4.0 gridview and it shows my database attributes. And I added a button to update the database. I want to go to another page to add some values when user clicks those buttons. How can i go to another page like anotherpage.aspx by clicking button?

Thanks

Comment: this might be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185775/retrieving-and-displaying-dynamic-content-from-sql-database-into-asp-net-pages/10186235#10186235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do this:

```
Response.Redirect("page.aspx")
```

(Or) do this

```
Server.Transfer("page.aspx", )
```